# Python, find number string in one file, match that string inside of line from another file and replace string in first file with line from second file

Tags: python, string, powershell, file, replace

File 1: HTML file generated from a Salesforce ticket report.

File 2: Text file with the same ticket numbers from the ticket report in File 1, but each line is formatted as HTML hyperlinks with the ticket numbers and URLs embedded.

Objective: Parse through File 1 for 9-digit ticket numbers, match those ticket numbers with the same ticket numbers embedded in hyperlink code from File 2, and replace each ticket number in File 1 with the corresponding line (hyperlink) from File 2.

To summarize: Replace ticket numbers in an HTML file with corresponding lines of hyperlink code from a text file.

*Doesn't necessarily need to be a Python solution, but it's for Windows.

Comment: We're here to help you with your code not to code for you. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well, I've spent over a month trying to solve this problem with PowerShell, VBScript, batch files, and now Python.

I could provide the Python "code" that I have, but it's worthless as I have no experience with Python.

I posted a question a few weeks ago with my semi-working PoweShell code (trying to accomplish the same task) and I was scolded for including the code in the wrong format or something.

And so I didn't get much help on that question either.